How did the packets travel from WLAN to Ethernet port on my wireless router?
Currently, I use an optical modem to perform the functions of a router(Strict meaning) and modem, and it also has a DHCP server.
For my own wireless router, I only connected its LAN port to the LAN port of the optical modem and turned off the DHCP server on my wireless router.
My understanding is that I am now using my own wireless router as a wireless access point and switch. I can access the internet normally now.
I would like to ask how the data packets from my computer reach the optical modem. Do the packets first get encapsulated by WLAN, transmitted to the router, where the router removes the WLAN header, and then re-encapsulates them with a MAC address into an Ethernet packet to be sent to the optical modem? I'm not exactly sure, but it seems like this is not something that just a switch can handle.

Connecting a router that way basically reduces it to a WAP, bridging between Wi-Fi and Ethernet. However, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].

I am sorry for that, I will choose a right place next time : (

It works like any other LAN device does except that it uses the wireless network connection to your LAN instead of the wired connection. Basically the wifi access point function of your wireless router to provide a switching function between the wifi and the wired network. That's it. It's just normal layer 2 networking between wifi and wired network and eventually traffic destined to the internet leaves via your router (the optical one provided by the ISP, I assume).

I think you are right. The wireless port that devices connected to and the ethernet LAN ports are inherently connected in the wireless router we bought. And I think the destination MAC address of packets is the MAC address of default gateway without changing during the process.
